# Timezone problem when combining Tomcat9 with MySQL8

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

I use the `time TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3);` for the time column so it will be automatically set when I insert a new line.

According to [MySQL TIMESTAMP Type Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html),

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

It seems fine when use SELECT() function in the CLI:

````
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
+--------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) |
+--------------------------------+
| 08:00:00                       |
+--------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select time from databasename.tablename;
+-------------------------+
| time                    |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-12-16 22:02:45.891 |
| 2018-12-16 22:02:46.032 |
| 2018-12-16 22:02:46.169 |
| 2018-12-16 22:02:46.304 |

```data following```
````

However when I try to display it in Tomcat based JSP page use:

```
<td align="center">
<c:set var="time" value="${row.time}" />
<fmt:setTimeZone value="GMT+8" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" />
</td>
```

it displays a strange time which is 14 hours earlier then GMT+8, while printing the current time is normal:

```
<td align="center" colspan="14">
<h1>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />
</h1>
</td>
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

PS:
the `row` is from the [Official Tomcat Connect Tutorial](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_2_Example)'s demo codes in `4. Test code` as below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/TestDB">
select id, foo, bar from testdata
</sql:query>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Results</h2>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
    Foo ${row.foo}<br/>
    Bar ${row.bar}<br/>
</c:forEach>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the output when adding timezone parameter to the pattern and not setting the timezone before?

Comment: @Selaron Add or remove the line `<fmt:setTimeZone value="GMT+8" />` make the same output. I temporarily changed it to GMT-6 so it will display the right time.

Comment: What TZ is Java using internally? When you do `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp`, the date will be converted from the JVM's timezone into the MySQL server's timezone and when you do `ResultSet.getTimestamp` the reverse should happen.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I used `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai` in Tomcat's `catalina.sh`, can this change the Java internal TZ?

Comment: Using `user.timezone` is exactly how you should set the JVM's timezone, so that's fine. The JDBC driver should be converting your objects between the JVM's time zone and the server's time zone correctly. Is `{row}` a `java.sql.ResultSet` or is it an object of some other type? Is it possible that there are other conversions in your code that you aren't considering?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I'm a new learner to these so I'm not really sure about the type, I just modified the codes from Offical Tomcat Connecting Tutorial. I've edited the question and added the details.

Comment: What happens if you add a `Z` to the date-format pattern? What time zone does it report?